# CURL - Writing to a file in Python

Tags: python, curl, file-io, autodesk-forge

I am working on a project to convert .sldprt file to .obj using [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-source-file-to-obj/) tutorial using a Python script. The last part of this tutorial deals with downloading the converted file from the forge servers to the local machine. This can easily be accomplished using the following command-line command

```
sudo curl -X "GET" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -v "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/$SURN/manifest/$OURN" -o $OUTFILE
```

$TOKEN is the access token, $OURN is the output file URN and $OUTFILE is the output file name.

To accomplish the same thing with a python script, I have tried the following

```
### Downloaded the converted file
url =  BASE_URL + 'modelderivative/v2/designdata/' + urn + '/' + OURL
headers = {
'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN
}
with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w+') as f:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=f)
```

However, the output file is always zero bytes

Can anyone guide me on how to accomplish the same thing using a Python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `data=f` from your request and do `f.write(r.text)` after.

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't look like you are writing to the file. try this,

```
### Downloaded the converted file
url =  BASE_URL + 'modelderivative/v2/designdata/' + urn + '/' + OURL
headers = {
'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN
}
with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w+') as f:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=f)
    f.write(r.json())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get the following error: raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: instead of r.json() just use r.text